# PageIterator.IterateAsync() with filter Invalid filter clause

Tags: c#, iterator, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am calling Graph with the SDK in C#, my initial request works fine and I get 200 results but the iterator returns an error with an invalid filter clause.

The initial call with the filter works perfectly am I calling the iterator correctly?

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-25);
Date graphDate = new Date(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
string weekendingFilterdate = graphDate.ToString();

string timesheetItemFilterString = $"Fields/FridayDate eq '{weekendingFilterdate}'";
var resultsList = new List<ListItem>();
        try
        {
            var results = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteName].Lists[listName].Items.Request().Expand("fields").Filter(filterString).GetAsync();
            var pageIterator = PageIterator<ListItem>.CreatePageIterator(_graphServiceClient, results, (i) => { resultsList.Add(i); return true; });
            await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.LogInformation(ex.Message);
        }
        return resultsList;



Error = {Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-08-10T08:15:21
    request-id: 3fd61829-ab4e-4acc-bd37-f9064a0296f2
    client-request-id: 3fd61829-ab4e-4acc-bd37-f9064a0296f2
ClientRequestId: 3fd61829-ab4e-4acc-b...
```

I have also tried the below pattern and still get the same error, the initial request returns 200 items but the iterator throws an error:

```
        List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
            {
                new QueryOption("$filter",
                  filterString)
            }; 

            var results = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteName].Lists[listName].Items.Request(options).Expand("fields").GetAsync();
            var pageIterator = PageIterator<ListItem>.CreatePageIterator(_graphServiceClient, results, (i) => { resultsList.Add(i); return true; });
            await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

**UPDATE**

This was an issue in the version of the SDK and was fixed in the latest release:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296833/graph-sdk-c-pageiterator-iterateasync-invalid-filter-clause

Comment: I'd suggest you try to use `$"FridayDate eq '{weekendingFilterdate}'"` instead. The Fields path looks weird to me.

Comment: Without Fields/ I get an invalid Filter clause error on the first request, it just seems to fail when the iterator attempts to get the next page